# I am using redux to build an uber clone I encounter Syntax Error none of these files exist

Tags: react-native

Unable to resolve module ../utils/reactBatchedUpdates from D:\uber-clone\node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules\react-redux\utils\reactBatchedUpdates(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- node_modules\react-redux\utils\reactBatchedUpdates\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  16 | var _withSelector = require("use-sync-external-store/shim/with-selector");
  17 |

> 18 | var _reactBatchedUpdates = require("../utils/reactBatchedUpdates");
> |                                     ^
> 19 |
> 20 | var _batch = require("../utils/batch");
> 21 |

ABI46_0_0facebook::ABI46_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
ABI46_0_0facebook::ABI46_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
FF408738-D75B-3061-AD99-4A929C0162D2
FF408738-D75B-3061-AD99-4A929C0162D2
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
A408A063-A023-3AAA-A674-0FF01607F818
A408A063-A023-3AAA-A674-0FF01607F818
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
F9E6CF6F-3B15-3C66-8C35-951AFD4D0CC4
UIApplicationMain
Expo Go
1A4BE407-C230-309B-AEAB-8E9C62BD377A

Comment: import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";

export default function App() {
  return (
<Provider store={store}>
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text>Let's build Uber</Text>
<StatusBar style="auto" />
   </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

Comment: What solutions have you tried already? Explain what steps you've taken so that responders know that you tried to resolve this on your own first.